# ¿Cómo obtener valor de input text que esta dentro de una DataTable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

Tengo la siguiente tabla con 2 input text, que reflejan cantidad y precio respectivamente, el punto es que debo llenar los input para luego extraer los datos de cada fila, lo cual no logro hacer.

Mi idea era utilizar el metodo rows().data(), pero solo obtiene un objeto con los primeros 3 datos los cuales lleno por defecto y no los datos que escribi en los input. ¿Podrian ayudarme?

Adjunto codigo.

```
tablaInput = $("#tablaInput").DataTable({
                "destroy":true,
                "data":datos,
                "columns" :[
                {"data": "name"},
                {"data": "code_product"},
                {"data": "stock"},
                {
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return ' <input id="cant" type="text"> ';
                    }
                },
                {
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return ' <input id="price" type="text"> ';
                    }
                },
                {
                    render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                        return ' <button class="btn btn-danger" id="btnDel"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button> ';
                    }
                }]                    
            });
           
        });

    $("#btnGuardar").on('click',function (){
      var data = tablaInput.rows().data();

      console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: Aver si entendi, lo que quieres es que cuando un usuario inserte texto en el input y le de enter quieres obtener ese texto no?

Comment: Exacto o bueno, no al darle enter, sino con cualquier otro tipo de evento. Lo que me gustaría es obtener el texto que escribo en el input, de una manera u otra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al cambiar el valor de el input con id `cant` deberia hacer console.log del valor actual del input, lo mismo con los demas inputs, checkea si funciona por que no estoy muy familiarizado con jquery, saludos

```
$("#cant").on('input',function (event){
      console.log(event.target.value)
      
});
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, funciono.